# 3rd party mac developer application (no profiles currently match) issue

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, certificate

I have this strange issue. Xcode target does not find my 3rd party mac developer certificates.
I can still build, run, submit apps, but Apple sends me emails to fix the issue (no certificate) in the next release.

This is what I tried so far:

- Recreated all Mac certificates (Mac App, Instlaller, Developer and  WWDR)
- Deleted old certificates from Keychain
- Downloaded new ones and installed all in both login and system (just in case)
- Restart computer, clean Xcode, even start a new dummy project

Am I missing anything? I Recently got a new Macbook, so I'm running it on Lion and my data is transferred from SL, Xcode 4.1 and Xcode 4.2 behaves the same way.

Target: No profiles currently match (only my iPhone certificates show up) (I just copied the name from the project to make the submission process happy)
[image: Target]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I don't know what happened with the 3rd Party Mac Developer Application profile, it used to be good but it looks not anymore.

I had to generate a new Mac Provisioning Profile:

1. Goto: https://developer.apple.com/certificates/
2. Click "Provisioning Profiles"
3. Click "Create Profile"
4. Kind:Production Provisioning Profile etc.
5. Download and install (Double Click)
6. Your new provisioning profile will show up in Xcode/Organizer/Provisioning Profiles and should be auto-selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using iCloud or push, then you don't need any profiles, you can just select the identity with (no profiles currently match)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1759/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011373